# My Haskell word count program

Tags: haskell

Here's my first significant Haskell program - it presents a count of each word seen on stdin. Any comments are welcome.

```
import Data.Map

emptyMap = empty :: Map String Integer

countWord m s = alter (\x -> case x of
                               Nothing -> Just 1
                               Just n -> Just (n+1)) s m

mapPairs m = concat [ k ++ ": " ++ (show v) ++ "\n" | (k,v) <- toList m ]

mapTotal = sum . elems

mapOutput m = (mapPairs m) ++ "Total words: " ++ (show (mapTotal m)) ++ "\n"

wc = interact $ mapOutput . (foldl countWord emptyMap) . words
```

Some of the questions I have are:

- Am I using Map efficiently here? (I realize there are other solutions which do not use a Map - the main point of this exercise was to learn how to use Data.Map.)
- How can I make sure that emptyMap, countWord and mapTotal all use the same integral type (`Int` vs. `Integer`)? For instance, the type of mapTotal is `Map a Integer -> Integer`, and so I'll get a type error if I change the definition of emptyMap to `empty :: Map String Int`. Ideally I'd like to make the choice between `Int` and `Integer` in one place for all three definitions.

Comment: You might like `fromListWith`; you can replace `foldl countWord emptyMap` with something like `fromListWith (+) . flip zip (repeat 1)` and skip defining `countWord` at all.

Answer (score 12):

Your usage of `Data.Map` is sound. I see nothing that could be improved as long as you stay with `Data.Map`.

If you give all of the functions explicit type declarations, so that the Monomorphism Restriction doesn't apply, you can use generic integral types:

```
mapTotal :: Integral i => Map a i -> i
```

Some quick style-related things you could change:

**First:**

```
(\x -> case x of
  Nothing -> Just 1
  Just n -> Just (n+1))
```

... is the same as

```
Just . maybe 1 (+1)
```

**Second:**

You don't need parens around many of your function calls; if you have something like `a +.- (foo bar baz) ¤:* b`, it means the same thing as `a +.- foo bar baz ¤:* b` because every operator has lower precedence than function application.

**Third:**

You use very long indentations. A tip is to insert newlines after `=` and before control structures like `case` to make the code more compact. I find [this style](http://snapframework.com/docs/style-guide) to be quite good.

Comment: I should probably have waited until this question was migrated to CodeReview; thought it already had been...

Comment: The first snippet is actually `maybe (Just 1) (Just . (+1))`, not `maybe 1 (+1)`.

Comment: [**`Data.Map.Strict`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Map-Strict.html) may be more efficient since he is only counting.

Answer (score 5):

It's good code, except for the strictness problem : you're accumulating big thunks of ((1+1)+1)+1.. in your Map. If you're handling long texts with repeated words, you could even end up having a stack overflow when you're finally computing them (in your "mapPair").

In your solution, you'll have to do :

```
Just n -> Just $! (n+1)
```

so that the result is evaluated before Just is applied.

Other solutions :

```
countWord w m = alter ((Just $!) . maybe 1 (+1)) w m
```

or

```
fromListWith' :: (v->v->v) -> [(k,v)] -> Map k v
fromListWith' f = foldl' ins empty 
   where ins m (k,v) = insertWith' f k v m

countWords :: String -> Map String Integer
countWords = fromListWith' (+) . flip zip (repeat 1) . words
```

Any of these solutions will work like your original one but should be a bit faster and less memory hungry, though it is possible that GHC was already optimising that (if you were using -O or -O2).